# Understanding the action that comes with $H^1_{cont}(G_K,GL_n(\mathbb{C}_p))$?

Tags: galois-representations, galois-cohomology

I need to look through Sen's "Continuous Cohomology and p-Adic Galois Representations" 1990 paper, but I have confused myself.

What is the $G_K$-action on $GL_n(\mathbb{C}_p)$, that makes it into a $G_K$-module?

He states that "Continuous cohomology refers to a theory in which the modules are given the topology induced by the valuation of the underlying field".

Thanks!

Comment: Do you know how $G_K$ acts on $\mathbb C_p$?

Comment: $\bar{K}$ has a topology from from the unique extension of the valuation on $K$. Then the elements of $G_K$ are continuous so extend to $\mathbb{C}_p$ by continuity.

So the action would be just evaluation. I'm not sure though how to extend that to an action on $GL_n(\mathbb{C}_p)$?

Comment: @Mathmo123 Sorry, I forgot to @ you in my comment there, still getting to grips with using StackExchange :)

Comment: You can just let $G_K$ act on $\mathrm{GL}_n(\mathbb C_p)$ entry-by-entry! Since matrix multiplication boils down to polynomials is the coefficients, the $G_K$ action respects multiplication.

Comment: @Mathmo123 Can I clarify how to define this without making reference to fixing some basis?

Comment: Well when you write $\mathrm{GL}_n(\mathbb C_p)$, you've already implicitly fixed a basis. But I guess your setup is that you have a vector space $V$ over $\mathbb C_p$ and you want to understand the Galois action on $\mathrm{Aut}(V)$. If $\phi$ is an automorphism and $\sigma\in G_K$, then $\sigma\phi$ is the automorphism $v\mapsto\sigma(\phi(\sigma^{-1}(v)))$.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/134975/discussion-between-djones-and-mathmo123).